# Set Variabled in Data Row Attribute in Data Test Methods

Tags: c#, mstest

I'm trying to test my DataMethod with strings which has variable interpolation in it.
eg: `$"MyString...{MyValue}"`
I am facing CS0182 error. saying `An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type`

Here is my DataTestMethod

```
[DataTestMethod]
[DataRow(@$"::::L:f9cda16c-50d8-4a4b-9b8c-a80b1915c3e7;Expires:{DateTimeOffset.UtcNow:u};")] //Facing Error here
public void WhenSomeAssignedAppsStringHasMissingAppTypes()
{         
    Assert.ThrowsException<FormatException>(() => { reconstructedSomeAssignments = AppsWithExplicitAssignmentsCacheItem.Create(cacheString); });
    Assert.IsNull(reconstructedSomeAssignments);
    Assert.IsNull(reconstructedSomeAssignments);
}
```

How do I create a DataRow if I need to test it with different inputs in my case?

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use `Member data-driven tests`. You can read more about them within the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/how-to-create-a-data-driven-unit-test?view=vs-2022#member-data-driven-test).

If you stick to my suggestion, your test may look like this:

```
[TestMethod]
[DynamicData(nameof(TestData))]
public void WhenSomeAssignedAppsStringHasMissingAppTypes(string arg)
{         
    Assert.IsNotNull(arg);
}

public static IEnumerable<object[]> TestData
    => new[] { new object[] { @$"::::L:f9cda16c-50d8-4a4b-9b8c-a80b1915c3e7;Expires:{DateTimeOffset.UtcNow:u};" } };
```

Another option (that I personally prefer) is to use a method as a dynamic data source, instead of a property.

```
[TestMethod]
[DynamicData(nameof(GetTestData), DynamicDataSourceType.Method)]
public void WhenSomeAssignedAppsStringHasMissingAppTypes(string arg)
{         
    Assert.IsNotNull(arg);
}

public static IEnumerable<object[]> GetTestData()
{
    yield return new object[] { @$"::::L:f9cda16c-50d8-4a4b-9b8c-a80b1915c3e7;Expires:{DateTimeOffset.UtcNow:u};" };
}
```